# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Android.Content.Intent.GetStringExtra(string)'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();

    //Find our audio and notificaton managers
    audioManager = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(AudioService);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(WifiService);

    string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData") ?? "Data not available";
```

> Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
>   'Android.Content.Intent.GetStringExtra(string)' (CS0120)

I keep getting this error for the last line of the code. I am trying to pass data from a qr code to the next activity the same way they do it in [here](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/blob/master/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/PassDataToActivity/Activity2.cs#L24)

I am not sure how to fix this problem and I have tried creating it static which didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStringExtra` is a non-static method. This means that you need an object to call it. For `getStringExtra`, you need an `Intent` object to call it, not the class.

So how do you get an intent object? In an activity, you can use `getIntent` to get the intent that is passed to the activity. Now you have the object, you can call `getStringExtra` on the object returned:

```
var obj = getIntent();
var someString = obj.getStringExtra(someArgs);
```

You can simplify this to

```
var someString = getIntent().getStringExtra(someArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

GetStringExtra is used to pass data between two activities. You put only one of that activity... Did you use this feature correctly ?

More information here : https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data from Activity1 to Activity2 as below:

Activity1 Passing Data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);

intent.putExtra("key","value");

startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2 Getting Data, Write below code in your Activity2 onCreate method

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```